# Правильное проигрывание анимации

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть 2d персонаж с коллайдером и `Rigidbody2d`. Также у него есть две анимации: покоя и ходьбы. Есть переходы между ними в  `Animator` в зависимости от скорости.

Есть третья анимация, анимация прыжка,  на которую также есть переход  в зависимости от `bool` переменной `IsGrounded`. Персонаж прыгает по нажатию клавиши пробел, но слишком быстро приземляется и `IsGrounded` становится `false`, анимация не успевает проиграться и переходит к анимации "покой".

Как сделать, чтобы персонаж прыгал и находился в воздухе или над землей пока не проиграться анимация, а не наоборот?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В *Unity* у *Mecanim* есть такая штука как **[BlendTree](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/class-BlendTree.html)** (Деревья смешивания). Они нужны для смешивания различных анимаций объекта. Именно его можно и использовать в данном случае. Однако для этого придется немного больше подзаморочиться. Вот список шагов:

1. Вместо состояния (`State`) нужно создать `Blend Tree`. И назвать его соответственно, например "Jump".

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Вместо того, чтобы из набора спрайтов с прыжком делать одну анимацию, придется сделать по одной анимации на каждое изображение. То есть, если в анимации прыжка участвует 12 изображений, то придется создать 12 анимаций и разместить по одному изображению в каждом. Назвать например Jump1, Jump2, Jump3 и т.д.
3. При создании этих нескольких анимаций все состояния (States) появятся в окне аниматора (Animator) Их надо будет оттуда удалить.
4. Сделать двойной клик на `Blend Tree` с именем `Jump`. Попадешь в другую вкладку:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Нужно будет нажать `Add Motion Field` по количеству анимаций прыжка. А также установить зависимость анимации от параметра `vSpeed`, то есть от параметра вертикальной скорости. И выбрать желательный диапазон. Например от -5 до 5:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Здесь можно тонко настроить анимацию. Как видим можно поставить срабатывание любой анимации любого кадра в любое время (смотри параметр `Thresh` а также голубенькие волны сверху справа - их можно двигать и регулировать). Также там можно задавать даже скорость каждой анимации.

   На данном изображении видно, что пока значение вертикальной скорости больше нуля, то будут проигрываться анимации 1–6 (прыжок вверх), если скорость меньше нуля — 7–12 (падение)
5. Переход из прыжка в состояние `Exit` если `Ground == true`

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Ну и через скрипт нужно теперь передавать значение нашей переменной `vSpeed`

   ```
   void FixedUpdate() {
       //...
       animator.SetFloat("vSpeed", rb.velocity.y);
   }
   ```

   Соответственно при клике на клавишу прыжка значение `velocity.y` у `rigidBody2D` меняется и передается в меканим и происходит прыжок